# Test case for child components onClick function

Tags: testing, jestjs, enzyme, chai, sinon

I want to test the onClick functionality of `MenuPopover.Item id={3}` if it was called once or not after clicking on it.

```
import React from 'react';
import copy from 'copy-to-clipboard';

const TableMenu = ({show, target, onClick, onHide, addedType, disable, readonly, rowId, supportRestore, supportDelete, isRestored}) => (
    <MenuPopover
        onClick={onClick}
        onHide={onHide}>
        {!readonly && (addedType ?
            <MenuPopover.Item id={1} label='Delete' disabled=true/> :
            <MenuPopover.Item id={2} label='Restore' disabled=false/>
        )}
        <MenuPopover.Item id={3} onClick={() => copy(rowId)} label='Copy'/>
    </MenuPopover>
);
```

Test case written so far

```
const onCopySpy = sinon.spy();
const props = {
    ///
    onCopy: onCopySpy,
    ///
};

it('check method onCopy called', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TableMenu {...props}/>);
    expect(wrapper.find('MenuPopover').children()).to.have.lengthOf(2);
    wrapper.find(MenuPopover.Item).... //Test case to call the onClick function
    expect(onCopySpy.calledOnce).to.eql(true);
});
```

Comment: There's onClick in the code you posted but you're using onCopy.

Comment: `wrapper.find('MenuPopover').props().onCopy();` is wrong. Using this statement i'm getting MenuPopover's props. But instead i want MenuPopover.Item's props.

Comment: String selector should be used for components as the last resort because it's unreliable. It should be `wrapper.find(MenuPopover.Item)` for that component.

Comment: @EstusFlask Ok. So how do i test the onClick functionality for it now?

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry, I'm bit new to testing. Can u plz give an example how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: If you're new to testing, you may want to ditch Sinon and Chai because they require additional efforts to be seamlessly integrated with Jest and still lack some (auto-mocking), while Jest already has most functionality they offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy` needs to be mocked in tests:

```
import copy from 'copy-to-clipboard';
jest.mock('copy-to-clipboard', () => sinon.spy());

...

const wrapper = shallow(<TableMenu {...props}/>);
wrapper.find(MenuPopover.Item).props().onClick();
expect(copy.calledOnce).to.eql(true);
```

This can be alternatively done with `simulate` but it [does the same thing internally](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#common-gotchas).

Comment: I'm getting the below error while simulating the onClick function `TypeError: reselectPrevious is not a function`

Comment: This means that copy-to-clipboard wasn't mocked for some reason, despite `jest.mock`. Make sure `jest.mock` is there. This shouldn't be normally required because it's hoisted but try to place it first in the file above `import`s.